# Match request URL params with rails routes via recognize_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, rack

I want to check if any incoming request actually exists in routes.rb as an entry via `recognize_path` like this

```
def path_exists?(path)
  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)
  true
  rescue
   false
end
```

This works for most URLs but if the URL has a parameter, then it fails to recognize it.

**Example:**

In routes.rb, say I have an entry like this

```
put "foo/bar/:param" => "foo#bar"
```

and the incoming request URL is of the form `/foo/bar/5`

Then the function `recognize_path` doesn't recognize the URL as the value of the parameter is `5` but it is matched with `:param`

How do I match requests that have parameters to their entries in routes.rb using `recognize_path` or any other similar function?

**Reason**

I'm filtering out malicious attempts to hit the server using random URLs like */dump.sql.tar.gz*, */conf.xz*, etc using the gem [rack::attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack) and [throttling](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack#throttling) requests whose URLs are not a part of routes.rb. Hence the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that with the following snippet:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a.reduce(false) do |exists, route|
 route.path.to_regexp.match?(path) || exists
end
```

But I do think the best choice is handling 404 errors using custom logic. Why doing what the router already does for you? Here's an example:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
# This will route any exceptions caught to your router Rack app. Now you'll want to define routes to display those errors yourself:

# config/routes.rb
get "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"
get "/422", :to => "errors#unacceptable"
get "/500", :to => "errors#internal_error"
```

(Extracted from http://web.archive.org/web/20141231234828/http://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails)

Then you can do whatever logic you want to do on `ErrorsController`

Comment: Upon further analysis of how our app handles the error, it appears that we actually do use custom logic for it. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!  
I tried using the code snippet you suggested and had some errors along the way but with your snippet as the base, I was able to modify it to get the desired functionality.  
Further, I was introduced to the `ActionDispatch::Journey::Route` object via the above snippet. Thanks for that.  
I'll type in the code that works for me via a different logic but mark this as the answer as it definitely helped. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def path_exists?(req_current)
 path_exists_val = false
 Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(req_current) do |route, params|
  if route.required_defaults[:controller] and route.required_defaults[:action]
   path_exists_val = true
  end
 end
 path_exists_val
end
```

This is the code that I ended up going with to match all the possible URLs with their respective controller and action using the `ActionDispatch::Journey::Route` object which I learned about from @cesartalves answer to the question and hence marked that as the answer.

Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome!

*PS. I'm new to Ruby on Rails.*

Comment: Hey again. In stackoverflow we avoid open-ended questions and suggestions, and we focus solely on giving answers to clearly-defined problems. If you need suggestions for the code, you might want to find a more open-ended forum of discussion about rails :)